# Excel: Create or Replace Table statement not working in Excel Get Data From OBDC

Tags: excel, google-bigquery

I have a set of queries that are pulling data into my Excel workbook. I'm using the "Get Data from OBDC" feature in Excel. All of my data pulls are SELECT statements and they run fine.

I also want to add a query that "CREATE or REPLACE TABLE" in the Excel workbook so I don't have to go to GBQ separately to run this query. Is there anyway to do this in Excel?

Below is the code I am running...

CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE `table_A` as(

SELECT
item_a,
item_b,
item_c

FROM `table_B`
)

ERROR I'm getting: "This native database query isn't currently supported."

**Is there a way to use an Create or Replace statement in the Excel Get Data from OBDC feature?**

Comment: Try adding a select statement after your statement, because it needs to be a select in the query as well. `CREATE OR REPLACE ...............; SELECT 1;`

Comment: I still get the same error:

Unable to connect
We encountered an error while trying to connect.
Details: "This native database query isn't currently supported."

I wonder if the CREAT OR REPLACE statement in general isn't supported in Excel?